# Add text before every vowel

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace, char

Hello I'm trying to add the String OB before every vowel(A,E,I,O,U) in my text. I can assume that the text is made up of all capital letters, no spaces or punctuation. These are handled by other methods I was able to create.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static String obify(String s){

    String text = s;
    String[] capVowels = {"A", "E", "I", "O", "U"};
    for (String vow : capVowels){
        text = text.replace(vow, "OB" + vow);
    }
    return text;
}
```

but when I pass it a sting it prints two OB before the first vowel.
Example input: HELLOWOLD , output: HOBOBELLOBOWOBOLD

Any help would be appreciated with an explanation.

Comment: The problem with doing this in a loop is you add more vowels with each iteration, ie the "O" in "OB"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to replace all the vowels with *"OB{vowel}"* via `String#replaceAll`. For example

```
final String test = s.replaceAll("[AEIOU]", "OB$0");
```

The `$0` represents the matched string, ie the vowel.

---

The reason you're getting duplicate "OB" strings in the result is because of your for-loop. The problem is you add more vowels with each iteration, ie the "O" in "OB", so when you get up to your "O" iteration, it's replacing the ones you added.

Comment: Thank you this worked great and was very efficient. Why the "final" on the variable? Also, If it's not too much to ask do you know why my code repeated the OB on the first vowel?

Comment: Ok, see that now, sorry very new.

Comment: @Aztolz I've added the extra info to my answer so it's all in one place.